# Splitting a variable with nominal and numeric values

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, data-transformation, large-data, continuous-data

I have a variable that has both numeric and nominal components. The source has a documentation which helps in identifying which is which and for splitting into their proper components. I will do modeling on these data later on (R or WEKA).

There are several of them and one of it is the `size` variable: the numeric components are 0 to 70 and the nominal values are `<10`, `10-20` up to `60-70`. The nominal part corresponds to unclear interviews with the patient, lost records (thus the inaccuracy) and other medical shortcomings.

My plan is to create two new variables - `size-num` and `size-nom` that will have the aforementioned to sets respectively as values.

Once I modify `size`, I face new problems:

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| id    | size    | size-num    | size-nom    |
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1     | >10     | ?           | >10         |
| 2     | 27      | 27          | ?           |
| 3     | 20-30   | ?           | 20-30       |
| 4     | 0       | 0           | 0           |
| 5     | <60     | ?           | <60         |
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

- In the numeric variable, how do I represent the removed nominal ones? If I just leave them out to be blanks then I will have to take into account missing values.
- In the nominal variable, how I do represent the numeric ones? I know that I can use them (numeric values) again but this will remove their continuous characteristic.

Comment: You can easily recode the numeric values to the nominal scale, but of course this loses information. It's also possible to keep the two types of measurement, and write a likelihood function that incorporates both kinds of information (though it may be risky to assume they both represent subpopulations with the same underlying distribution).

Comment: @Glen_b, could you give an example on the methods you provided?